# Mule: how to assign a Java/Spring bean's method call result to a flow variable

Tags: java, spring, mule, javabeans, invoke

I am new to Mule. I understand I can have"Java" or "Invoke" component in the Mule flow configuration. My question is: how can I assign the value returned by a Java method call to a Mule flow variable? ex. something like

```
<spring-bean name="myBean" .... />

<invoke object-ref="myBean" method="addTwoNumbers" methodArguments="#[var1], #[var2]" methodArgumentTypes="java.lang.Float, java.lang.Float" name="someName" doc:name="Invoke"/>

<set-variable variableName="addResult" value="???????" />
```

I need the "addResult" var to have the value of the previous invocation result, but how?

Thanks!

Comment: edit you question to include the code properly formatted

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The result of the spring bean will be the payload, so you can set it like so:

```
<set-variable variableName="addResult" value="#[payload]" />
```

However if you don't want to overwrite the existing payload you can use an `enricher`:

```
<enricher target="#[flowVars.addResult]">
   <invoke object-ref="myBean" method="addTwoNumbers" methodArguments="#[var1], #[var2]" methodArgumentTypes="java.lang.Float, java.lang.Float" name="someName" doc:name="Invoke"/>
</enricher>
```

Comment: And what if invoked method returns void?